# why bootboxjs scroll my page to top?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I use button as well as div but in all cases bootbox.js scroll my page to top.

```
$("#sampleButton").click(function(){
    bootbox.alert("hey");
});
```

Comment: Are you using `href="#"` or something like that on the `#samplebutton`? If so, use `href="javascript:void(0)"` instead

Comment: @wwarren no i am not using href my html code is <div class="btn btn-warning  btn-sm" id="sampleButton">Client</div>

Comment: show all the code. html + js.

Comment: html code :- <div class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="sampleButton">Client</div>   & java script :- $("#sampleButton").click(function(){
    bootbox.alert("hey");
});

Comment: please create jsfiddle to demonstrate your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve this problem by using [jquery-impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$("#sampleButton").click(function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault();
  bootbox.alert("hey"); 
});
```